# Stability of the following ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, stability-in-odes, stability-theory

Consider the following nonautonomous, nonlinear ODE:

$$y'(t)=\rho(W(t)y(t)+b(t)),$$

where $y(t),b(t)\in\mathbb{R}^{n},W(t)\in\mathbb{R}^{n,n}$ and $\rho:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is some nonlinear function that is applied element-wise.

A paper I'm reading claims that this ODE is Ljapunov stable if

$$\max_{i\in\{1,\cdots,n\}}Re(\lambda_i(J(t)))\leq 0\hspace{6pt}\forall t,$$

where $Re(\cdot)$ denotes the real part and $\lambda_i(J(t))\in\mathbb{R}$ is the $i^{th}$ eigenvalue of the Jacobian $J(t)\in\mathbb{R}^{n,n}$ of the righthand side of the ODE. The paper does neither prove this nor provide a reference to any known theorem proving this, which leaves me with the question:

Why is this true? Can anybody point me to a result that shows this?

I know similar results for linear, autonomous ODEs with and without small nonlinear perturbations, but I know no such result for the above nonlinear, nonautonomous ODE.

For reference, the paper claiming this is [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1705.03341) in equations (3.5) and (3.6).

Comment: What kind of stability?  What does $\rho$ look look like in concrete terms?  I don't think this can be answered without such input.  I'll try to check the paper if I have time, but anything you can add will help.  Cheers!

Comment: @RobertLewis Ljapunov stability and they seem to be claiming this for an arbitrary differentiable $\rho$. They later mention that in practice, $\rho$ will usually be monotonically increasing, but that is not a requirement for their claim in the paper. They make it sound as if their claim were obvious and common knowledge, that's what baffles me. Thank you very much for taking a look!

Comment: OK, thanks for the clarification.

Comment: No, this is not, in general, true. For a counterexample, due to Markus and Yamabe, of a two-dimensional system $x'(t)=A(t)x(t)$ with the real parts of the eigenvalues of $A(t)$ negative (and bounded away from zero) but which possesses an unbounded solution, see p.121 in Hale [Ordinary Differential Equations](https://books.google.com/books/about/Ordinary_Differential_Equations.html?id=LdTZJ4HwCv4C).

Comment: On the other hand, the authors write "if $\mathbf{K}(t)$ is changing sufficiently slow and ...". Indeed, there are results that, if the real parts of the eigenvalues are **negative** and bounded away from zero and change slow enough then the trivial solution *is* asymptotically stable.  But the weak inequality $\le0$ is not sufficient, even for the Lyapunov stability in the autonomous case: take $x'=Ax$ with $$A=\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\ 0&0\end{bmatrix},$$ for example.

Comment: Thanks a lot @user539887! And that is without even considering the nonautonomous part $b(t)$, which complicates things further. You wouldn't be able to point me to the results you're mentioning in your second comment by any chance, would you?

Comment: There are some early papers by Desoer.  I know a paper by V. Solo *On the Stability of Slowly Time-Varying Linear Systems* in Math. Control Signals Systems 7 (1994), 331–350. Some references are given in DaCunha *Instability results for slowly time varying linear dynamic systems on time scales*, J. Math. Anal. Appl. 328 (2007), 1278–1289.